# RC timer not reaching desired voltage

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to make a circuit that will light the led with progressive intensity one second after the circuit is powered. For that I created an RC net with tau equal to 1 sec. At 1 second I expect the Vb to reach 63% of the dc voltage(1.2v) which is ~0.7v, that will forward bias the transistor and the led will start lighting.
The problem I got is that the voltage at the test point gets stuck at 555 mv when I add the transistor. I'd expect it to eventually reach the 1.2v. Moreover, this doesn't happen if I reduce the RC values to, i.e 1K and 1mf, for maintaining the tau constant.

Why the voltage at the base of the transistor doesn't reach the 1.2v?

[image: circuit]

Comment: How much base current does your transistor need to light the LED? How much current can it get through a 1M resistor? Do you see the problem?

Comment: I thought that the current at the led was determined by the 5v and the 470 ohms resistor, which gives 10mA.

Comment: Well, yes, assuming that the transistor has minimal voltage drop. But what does it take to achieve that?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about how bipolar transistors work. You need significant current flowing into the base terminal, and a 1 megohm resistor probably will not provide enough current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the BJT to work properly you need enough current to flow through the base terminal, and in your case due to the high resistance you are only getting: 
$$ I= V/R $$
$$ I = 1.2/10^6 = 1.2 \mu A$$

Thus the base current is too low to function. While when you reduce the resistance to 1K ohms only, the base current will be 1.2mA which is sufficient enough.